# How to step into WCF asp.net service app from website using visual studio 19

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, api, wcf

I have a legacy vb.net restful api written as a service (service1.svc, .net framework 4.0). When I run it in VS2019 it launches the WCF Test Client which lists all my methods and presents a test page for each.  That's great, but I want to be able to step into the running instance from the calling website (also running in VS2019).  With ServiceStack and other API apps I have used this works just fine. I run the API under a different port on localhost and any breakpoint will be hit when the web app calls that route.

So in this case for example my web app will call:

`https://myServer.com/Service1.svc/v1/GetSomeData?value=1`

If I replace the server with local host:

`http://localhost:61202/Service1.svc/v1/GetSomeData?value=1`

I get a 400 Bad Request.

Interestingly if I corrupt the localhost url like this (which I did once):

`http://localhost:61202/Service1.svcservice1.svc/v1/GetSomeData?value=1`

The WCF app breaks in global.asax.vb on the Application_Error event with the exception:

`"The service '/Service1.svcservice1.svc' does not exist."`

So it is actually calling the service...which is good.

With the valid url, breakpoints at Application_BeginRequest and Application_AuthenticateRequest in the API are not hit when I make a call so it's not getting that far, which surprised me.

I think I am close to getting this to work but I don't know how to proceed for here.  I believe the localhost url is properly formed because that is the same form that works on the production server. It must be some other configuration in the API project.

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

RESTful services need to confirm that you are using webhttpbinding, and then refer to this link for how to publish a wcf service correctly:[WCF Service Publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-service-publishing)

Comment: I have a web.config and Service1.svc file in the project, and when the project is copied to IIS in the production server it runs just fine and javascript AJAX calls can hit the service, so it appears to be setup properly. I do not believe any deployment tool was used to generate the deployable version, I think it was built 'manually', so that my be an issue.

Comment: You can try the method in the official document to publish the service.